# Sprint integration: Adding / Removing topics to an MQTT inbound adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, mqtt, paho

As stated in the title: How can I add / remove a single or multiple topics to a started MQTT inbound adapter at runtime without stopping and resubscribing?

I am using a similar configuration to the example from [docs.spring.io](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.0.M3/reference/html/mqtt.html):

```
<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="mqttInbound"
client-id="${mqtt.default.client.id}.src"
url="${mqtt.url}"
topics="topic1, topic2, topic3"
client-factory="clientFactory"
channel="output"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically changing the subscribed topics is not currently supported. Please open an [Improviement JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: In case it's not clear, topics can include wildcards so that might be a viable work-around. See the Paho javadocs for more information.